# Libgdx Platformer 2d beginning adding enemies

Tags: java, libgdx

I have read The guide to implementing 2D platformers
http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/

I want to develop the second way (Type #2: Tile Based (Smooth))
Collision is still determined by a tilemap, but characters can move freely around the world.

I have made a class Enemy with position and velocity.

**How could I move the Enemy in the world when it is not visible in the screen yet? There is any GitHub example of this issue?**

I am not using Box2D. I have started with the Super Koalio Example:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/superkoalio/SuperKoalio.java

Comment: What is the issue? How does movement have anything to do with whether the enemy is on screen?

Comment: My problem is that the camera follow the player, and currently the enemy is displayed in a fixed position of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

My problem about rendering was solved using OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer